# Image not rendering after loops

Tags: java, graphics2d

I've recently started learning Java and am attempting to make a basic game. To render the map I have two boolean array's configured (arr_mapx, arr_mapy), these are then checked using two for loops and two if statements to determine if both are true. If both are true the image should render, but it does not. I have successfully rendered the image outside the loop so it is not a problem with the image variable or file.

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.drawImage(img_player1, int_player1_x, int_player1_y, this);
    if (map_drawn == false)
    {
        map_drawn = true;
        for(int int_x = 0; int_x < 20; int_x ++)
        {
            if(arr_mapx[int_x] == true)
            {
                for(int int_y = 0; int_y < 20; int_y ++)
                {
                    if(arr_mapy[int_y] == true)
                    {
                        g2.drawImage(img_obstacle, (int_x + 1)*32, (int_y + 1)*32, this);
                        //Appears to do nothing
                        showStatus("It Works!" + int_x + int_y +map_drawn);
                        //Draws fine, with correct variables
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put in some debug statements or use a debugger to see what is happening.  Without knowing what your data is, it is near to impossible to guess.

Comment: Are you seeing your "It Works!" messages?

Comment: I am seeing the "It Works!" message with all correct variables. I shall look into some debugging. Shall a google search for "java debug guide" do fine? Or is there a particular resource/guide you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the code to reduce nesting. (See code block below. Caveat: Just using a text editor so don't expect bug free code.) The first thing that popped out at me is that `map_drawn` is never set to `false`. It draws once and is set to true and on subsequent entries into the function you exit before drawing anything in the loops because the value of `map_drawn` never changed to `false` anywhere.

Tough to say where it should change since we're just seeing a small part of your game. Is there logic in another function to set the value of `map_drawn`?

By the way, be careful about what you do in the paint handler (that is what you're working in here). Custom animations like this can tough to debug because of the behavior of the function. For example, if you stop in it with a debugger and then run the paint function will fire off again right away because the display needs updating. I don't know what showStatus does but it should not be a dialog. It should be logging to console or somewhere else. You definitely do not want the user to interact with UI launched from paint!

Good luck!

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.drawImage(img_player1, int_player1_x, int_player1_y, this);

    if (map_drawn) return;

    map_drawn = true;

    for(int int_x = 0; int_x < 20; int_x ++)
    {
        if(!arr_mapx[int_x]) continue;

        for(int int_y = 0; int_y < 20; int_y ++)
        {
            if(!arr_mapy[int_y]) break;

            g2.drawImage(img_obstacle, (int_x + 1)*32, (int_y + 1)*32, this);
            //Appears to do nothing
            showStatus("It Works!" + int_x + int_y +map_drawn);
            //Draws fine, with correct variables
        }            
    }
}
```